# Why does Titan have lower surface gravity than the Moon when Titan is more massive?

Tags: gravity, titan

Reading on Wikipedia I saw that Titan is 80% more massive than the earth's moon but has only 85% the surface gravity. Why is this?

Comment: Titan is less dense than the moon?

Comment: As a more extreme example, Uranus' mass is over 14.5 times that of the Earth, but Uranus' "surface gravity" is about 89% of Earth's surface gravity.

Comment: The Moon is is basically rock, Titan is made up of about 50% ices.  Most of the outer moons and Ceres contain a significant amount of ices/water, so they have much lower density than the inner planets and our moon.

Comment: @user151558 While this is generally correct, it's a very brief and unsatisfying answer.   Surface gravity is a function of mass and radius (and sometimes speed of rotation).  Density is relevant, but it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @userTLK The comment is not generally correct. It *is* the specifically correct answer to this very elementary question. $g \propto \rho^{2/3} M^{1/3}$. Though saying that the radius of Titan is much bigger would have been equally valid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Surface gravitational acceleration on an object with mass $M$ and radius $R$ is given by
$$
g = \frac{GM}{R^2} \propto G\rho R
$$
where $\rho \propto M/R^3$ is the density of the object.
If one body has smaller surface $g$ than another, it must have smaller density $\rho$, smaller radius $R$, or both.
Titan is larger than Earth's Moon, so your observation about its surface gravity means Titan must be less dense than the Moon.  Wikipedia confirms:

- $R_\text{Titan} = 1.5 R_\text{Moon}$, but
- $\rho_\text{Moon} = 3.34\rm\,g/cm^3$ while Titan has only $\rho_\text{Titan} = 1.88\rm\,g/cm^3$.

Comment: So by that logic, Ganymede, the largest of our moons, is also the lightest?

Comment: I don't have any information about Ganymede's density or surface gravity --- I'd have to look it up.

Comment: No, the problem is you said "larger therefore less dense". This does not always hold

Comment: @Tosic Oh! That wasn't what I meant (note that Earth is larger than and denser than either the Moon or Titan). I've added a sentence which hopefully clarifies.